# MPAndroidChart is not updating

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have a hashmap like this

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> hash = new LinkedHashMap<>();
hash.put("2015-05-03", 100);
hash.put("2015-05-04", 110);
hash.put("2015-05-05", 90);
hash.put("2015-05-06", 40);
```

I want to design a LineChart via [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) but it is not working, diagram is not valid, nothing to show!it seems my codes are invalid.
here are my codes :

```
private void setChartData(LinkedHashMap<String, String> lastMonthMediaLikes)
    {

        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : lastMonthMediaLikes.entrySet())
        {
            xVals.add(entry.getKey());
        }



        ArrayList<Entry> vals1 = new ArrayList<>();
        int i = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : lastMonthMediaLikes.entrySet())
        {
            vals1.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(entry.getValue()), i));
            i++;
        }

        // create a dataset and give it a type
        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(vals1, "DataSet 1");
        set1.setDrawCubic(true);
        set1.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);
        //set1.setDrawFilled(true);
        set1.setDrawCircles(false);
        set1.setLineWidth(1.8f);
        set1.setCircleSize(4f);
        set1.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
        set1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        set1.setFillColor(Color.WHITE);
        set1.setFillAlpha(100);
        set1.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false);
        set1.setFillFormatter(new FillFormatter()
        {
            @Override
            public float getFillLinePosition(LineDataSet dataSet, LineDataProvider dataProvider)
            {
                return -10;
            }
        });

        // create a data object with the datasets
        LineData data = new LineData(xVals, set1);
        //data.setValueTypeface(tf);
        data.setValueTextSize(9f);
        data.setDrawValues(false);

        // set data
        chart.setData(data);
    }
```

Please advice, what should i do?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are setting the data via `setData(...)` but **you are not refreshing** the `View` by calling `invalidate()`.

This should do the job:

```
LineChart chart = ...;

chart.setData(...); // sets data & also calls notifyDataSetChanged()
chart.invalidate(); // refreshes chart
```

Comment: Don't forget to add: `chart.notifyDataSetChanged()` before `chart.invalidate()` so that your data refresh too.
I found this answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304132/5533514

Comment: `setData()` do this only at first time. On second, third and so on you'll need `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Try also changing `data.setDrawValues(false)`; to `data.setDrawValues(true)`;

Comment: Please make sure that the codes are correctly formatted when you post anything here.

Comment: Please do not post bare code, also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`mChart.clearValues();`