# How to refresh android mpchart graph without refreshing whole activity

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Hello i am using android MPAndroidChart library in my project. I want to refresh chart without refreshing activity page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check this might it help you. you can take it in some layout and reload it when you update data/nay other update.

Comment: Pragati i want to change yAxis max value both left and right side of graph. i have done the code on button click but graph can't change yAxis value.

Comment: chartView.notifyDataSetChanged(); // if list 
chartView.invalidate(); might help you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Where ever upon button click or spinner selection you need to update your graph just call a method:

```
chartView.notifyDataSetChanged();
chartView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Voted up for a simple yet effective answer.

Comment: Thank you - my app was crashing on the chart screen when user got back to it by pressing back, and I couldn't figure out why. adding otifyDataSetChanged() fixed the crash