# Reload a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, reload

everyone, my issue is :

I'm in ProfilFragment, that was generated with the Menu Drawer it extends Fragment, and I can't change this (it broke some other part).
 When I click on a button I want to refresh my current Fragment

```
// Reload current fragment
                        Fragment frg = null;
                        frg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_profil);
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.detach(frg);
                        ft.attach(frg);
                        ft.commit();
```

I found this on other StackOverflow issues but it didn't work for me.
`frg = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_profil);`
Always return null

Even if in my `mobile_navigation.xml`
I have

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_profil"
    android:name="com.example.pierregignoux.ui.profil.ProfilFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profil" />
```

Any help would be great, Thanks a lot.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why you want to reload a `Fragment`?

Comment: I add some db data to firebase to an Mpandroidchart, and it doesn't reload when data change

Comment: can you please check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303952/how-to-refresh-android-mpchart-graph-without-refreshing-whole-activity

Comment: For me nothing happen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run this

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Comment: So I do like                             getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(ProfilFragment.this).attach(ProfilFragment.this).commit(); but I receive Cannot detach Fragment attached to a different FragmentManager. Fragment ProfilFragment{ab662d} (22d9d467-dcfc-4dbc-8b00-fe827083f6a0) id=0x7f0900f6} is already attached to a FragmentManager.

Comment: dont use ProfilFragment.this just use this